# Composite key with JPA for a table with no PK

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I need a list of clients with a client id, clients of this id (client), and client name. The issue is that this table comes from a dblink without a PK

```
@Entity

@Table(name = "mytable", schema = "myschema")

public class Client {

    @Column(name = "clientid")
    @Id
    private Integer clientid;

    @Column(name = "client")
    private Integer client;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

With this code I'm getting the first name duplicated over and over till the end of the list, because theres no PK and I can't start the application without a PK. Something similar happens when I set the client column as PK (I get all the names correctly but the clientid field shows a wrong value. Is there a workaround for this?

Sample data:

**Wrong data (when setting clientid as @Id):**

```
[
  {
    "clientid": 99,
    "client": 81,
    "name": "Organization 1"
  },
  {
    "clientid": 99,
    "client": 81,
    "name": "Organization 1"
  },
  {
    "clientid": 99,
    "client": 81,
    "name": "Organization 1"
  }
]
```

**Wrong data (when setting client as @Id)**:

```
[
  {
    "clientid": 99,
    "client": 81,
    "name": "Organization 1"
  },
  {
    "clientid": 3,
    "client": 99,
    "name": "Organization 2"
  },
  {
    "clientid": 3,
    "client": 127,
    "name": "Organization 3"
  }
]
```

**What I should get: (clientid is correct in all cases)**

```
[
  {
    "clientid": 99,
    "client": 81,
    "name": "Organization 1"
  },
  {
    "clientid": 3,
    "client": 99,
    "name": "Organization 2"
  },
  {
    "clientid": 1,
    "client": 127,
    "name": "Organization 3"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you show us some sample data? Just few rows to better understand the problem you are facing.

Comment: Also... Are you allowed to modify your database? Just to understand our possibilities for any workaround.

Comment: @Lorelorelore I've just added a sample

Comment: The combination (clientid, client) does guarantee the unicity?

Comment: Each client has an unique id, and each clientid can have one of each client too. For example client 1 has a contract with client 127, 128 and 129. And client 2 has a contract with client 127, 128 and 129 too. Not sure if I did explain myself well.

Comment: @Lorelorelore I can't alter this table, only one person has this role.

Comment: So, can you have two records with, let's say,  {
    "clientid": 99,
    "client": 81}?

Comment: No, a clientid shouldn't have duplicated clients. In other words clientid is the people who we work for and client is the people who work for them. clientid has a name too, but that's on another table and I don't need it right now.

Comment: This link https://medium.com/@bhagyajayashani/composite-key-handling-using-idclass-annotation-in-spring-boot-java-26f40bbd38a2 can help you

Comment: So it's a composite primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a composite key to handle correctly your data. First, create another class that will represent the key:

```
public class ClientPK implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer clientid;

    private Integer client;

    /*Constructor, getters and setters here*/
}
```

And then update the class `Client` as it follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mytable", schema = "myschema")
@IdClass(ClientPK.class)
public class Client {

    @Column(name = "clientid")
    @Id
    private Integer clientid;

    @Column(name = "client")
    private Integer client;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

It is better to implement `hashCode` and `equals` method in `ClientPK` class.